# array of numbers as parameter of stored procedure (mysql) for select where in ()

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, stored-procedures

query

```
select *
from table
where field in (1,2)
```

in a stored procedure, where (1.2) - the parameter of the stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `myproc` (IN numbers)
```

1) tell me how to pass an array of numbers as a parameter to a stored procedure (do this via php)

```
$data = '(1,2,3)';
$result = $connection->query('CALL myproc($data)');
```

2) tell me how to check that passed to the stored procedure does not contain elements of an array or contains one element equal to 0

Answer (score 1):

I use FIND_IN_SET in sql:

```
select *
from table
where FIND_IN_SET(field, '1,2,3') > 0
```

'1,2,3' i form in php code

Answer (score 0):

try below code :

```
$data = '(1,2,3)';
$sql = sprintf("CALL myproc(%s)", $data);
$result = $connection->query($sql);
```

Comment: Ranjith, but how to use an array already in the stored procedure!

`CREATE PROCEDURE myproc (IN numbers !!!!!UNKNOWN TYPE!!!!!)`

and

`SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE field IN numbers`